# Contact not being maintained between objects

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have been working on a game where I have a certain issue that has been proven a bit of a challenge. I have asked concerning it but I hope to provide further clarification on the matter.
I have a game in spritekit with a character that collides on the ground. I also have code to prevent double jumping once the sprite is touching the "floor" I also have "wall" tiles where nothing occurs but more less to prevent a sprite from jumping when falling alongside a wall.

My issue is that, if my sprite walks across the floor and up to a wall. my NSLog displays "dont jump" as if to say my sprite cannot jump yet he is still on the floor. Pressing down my arrow key spams my console log which seems to show that contact is being made and broken with the floor as the sprite is "attempting to move off the tile" but is pushed back since he cannot. To better what I tried to describe, i have uploading a 20 second video to youtube also my contact code is below.
Would appreciate if anyone could see this issue as to why my sprite no longer contacts with my floor when it touches the wall.

Thanks

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nV3TaRupno

```
#pragma mark -  Contact
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
  uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
  if (collision == (PCFloorCategory|PCPlayerCategory)) {

    NSLog(@"Can jummp");
    onGround=YES;

  }
  if (collision == (PCWinCategory|PCPlayerCategory)) {

    NSLog(@"You win");
    [self endLevelWithSuccess:YES];

  }



- (void) didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {

  uint32_t contactTestb = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
  if (contactTestb == (PCPlayerCategory | PCWallCategory)) {

    NSLog(@"Please jumps");
    // jumpButtonDown=false;
  //  onGround = YES;
  }

  uint32_t contactTest = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
  if (contactTest == (PCPlayerCategory | PCFloorCategory)) {


    NSLog(@"dont jumps");
  //  jumpButtonDown=false;
    onGround = NO;
  }


}
```

**Move Method**

```
if (controlButtonDown) {

         SKNode *node= [bg childNodeWithName:@"player"];
        float angle = atan2f (touchY - 100, touchX - 100) ;
          SKAction *movePlayer=[SKAction moveByX:6*cosf(angle) y:0 duration:0.005];
      [node runAction: movePlayer];

 //  [_player update:currentTime];

  }
```

Comment: What method are you using to move your player?

Comment: @sangony update method in my main gamescene, I tried addding my update method in my player method however that didnt exactly help the issue

Comment: It could be your player is bouncing. Is your restitution property set to zero for your wall and your player?

Comment: @sangony Yes everything is zero, no its not "bouncing" as in the restitution bounce. its a different bounce. Like he's attempting to walk into the wall and being pushed back. if you look at the video my hand is holding down the "left" button so he's trying to "go left" but cant

Comment: Try using a different movement method for your player. Something like player.position = CGPointMake(player.position.x+5, player.position.y);

Comment: @sangony Same results, those are the two ways i normally move my player. do you have others?

Comment: You can also use physics to move an object but I always use the x/y +/- as it gives more precise control. From the code you have posted and what you said you tried, you should not have the problem you do. I hate to give you a cop out answer, but your issue must be somewhere else. Check your wall's physics body again, is your floor one smooth physics surface (sometimes having it broken up in tiles can also cause issues)? If all else fails, do you really NEED to fix this issue to make your game work? If your end goal is to prevent double jumping, you can ignore this issue.

Comment: @sangony Im looking at the physics but, i dont see anything wrong. I think ill move on and probably one day ill see the issue when not looking for it cause i have been on this one problem for weeks. Secondly I cant ignore the issue. if you can see from the video. whenever i touch a wall, i cant jump anymore even if contact is still being made with the floor. (NSlog says dont jump). a dirty fix was to turn the bool onGround to true after contact with the wall is lost but then that means i cannot jump when im standing on the floor, yet touching a wall

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55777/discussion-between-sleep-paralysis-and-sangony).